# How can I start the Windows Service without entering the user account password?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need to get an AD account when writing Windows Service.
If `this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User;`
The user account password needs to be entered when the service starts; if it is set to `NetworkService`, `LocalService`, `LocalSystem`, the user's AD account will not be captured.

Is there any way that the service can be started without entering the user AD when the service is installed?
Or is there another way for the Service to capture the AD account when the user logs in?

Thank you everyone! !!

Comment: You should only have to supply the password when *installing* the service, not every time it starts.

Comment: You want the service to get access to the user context of a normal user that logs on to the same machine? ie. if I install your service on my home computer, and then log on, you want your service to get access to my user, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: yes!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

AD domain account must have the [logon as service](https://serverfault.com/questions/771059/what-does-log-on-as-a-service-actually-mean) privilege. This allows a user to provide the password to install service only.

For example, I'm local admin but do not have AD `logon as service` permission. I can install service to be running using my domain user (I should provide the password to install the service). Then message box is shown `user has been granted logon as service` permission.

However I have to enter password one more time when is restarting the service next day (for example). This is because I do not have `logon as service` AD permission.